# How to clean ALL chracter from textarea

Tags: jquery, forms, textarea

I have a simple code, it cleans textarea after I press Enter Enter (one enter - just next line, as usual)

```
<textarea name="text" id="text" wrap="soft"></textarea>
```

and the .js (jquery based)

```
(function($) {
       $.fn.keyWatcher = function() {
              return this.keydown(function(evt){
                     var $this =  $(this);
                     var prevEvt = $this.data('prevEvt');
                     $this.trigger('multikeydown',[prevEvt,evt]);
                     $this.data('prevEvt',evt);
              });
       }; 
})(jQuery); //plugin for double key remember 

$('#text').keyWatcher().bind('multikeydown',function(evt,prevKey,currKey){
       var prKey = ((prevKey) ? prevKey.keyCode : "(none)");
       var cuKey = currKey.keyCode;
       if (cuKey == 13 && prKey == 13 ) { 
              $("#text").val('');
       }else{

       }
```

This code works almost fine - it clean my textarea, but it leave one empty line in start. It does't care how much lines I've entered before - 1 or 100, anyway it leave first line empty and put cursor to the second line.

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enter press has not yet been added to the field when you clear it. Change the event in the plugin to keyup instead so it triggers after the newline has already been added.

```
return this.keyup(function(evt){
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LtsAx/